# Will GWT compile if an annotation from server package is used in client code?

Tags: java, gwt, annotations

Will GWT compile my class if a custom annotation created under server package is referred by a shared Class ?

I need to annotate my record type classes with an annotation `@MyRecord` with some attributes.  So that I can get the attribute values at server side using reflection.  Since the record type class is under shared and used in both client & server code.

Note: `@MyRecord` is under server which cannot be compiled by GWT compiler.

Will it have any issues or any alternative way? Please help.

Comment: This sounds like one of those questions you could have tried first, and _then_ asked "why" or "why not" depending on what you discovered.

Comment: Hi @ColinAlworth, I apologize and thanks for pulling me out of laziness (I was not setup a GWT workspace because I have not started working and in planning stage).  After setting up GWT workspace and tried the same, the result is **It works!**. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting this after trying it myself.
I have the below classes/interfaces & an annotation in my GWT project.

```
agazhi
    client
        Agazhi.java
        AgazhiService.java
        AgazhiServiceAsync.java
    server
        AgazhiServiceImpl.java
        Soldier.java
        Staff.java
    shared
        Commander.java
    Agazhi.gwt.xml
```

Where `Commander` is my record type, `@Soldier` is an annotation and `Staff` is an interface.
The `Commander` class's object is passed from client to server throught Service.

Test Cases:

- If I compile the module with `@Soldier` annotation in Commander class
  it works.
- If I compile with `Staff` interface implemented on
  `Commander` class, it gives error

`No source code is available for type agazhi.server.Staff; did you forget to inherit a required module?`

Thanks everyone for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile with Staff interface implemented on Commander class, you may need to move Staff.java to the shared package, so that GWT compiler can translate it into JavaScript. Also, Staff.java should not depend on other classes which are not translatable to GWT compiler.

For more information, please refer to the module XML document: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModuleXml